# Squid Block/deny/disable cookies?

Tags: proxy, squid

I wanted to try blocking cookies for matched URLs. I read this [Squid - Users - "unset" or "remove" cookies on static content from the backend server](http://squid-web-proxy-cache.1019090.n4.nabble.com/quot-unset-quot-or-quot-remove-quot-cookies-on-static-content-from-the-backend-server-td4332346.html) and found I could do that, blocking cookies for all domains and URLs, with something like this:

```
request_header_access Cookie deny all
reply_header_access Set-Cookie deny all
```

But with proxying with this, a website with login capability still hold me being logged-in, and I checked cookies using a chrome extension (Edit this cookie) and found that it didn't work. So, how can achieve to do that? Thanks.

versions:
Squid Cache: Version 3.5.27
Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Are you intercepting HTTPS traffic or just allowing CONNECT request?

Comment: @Ginnungagap I didn't setup Squid for https. The website I tested is https:// website.